# Grails export plugin and convention over configuration

Tags: grails, export-to-excel

Normally, Grails controllers follow convention over configuration paradigm. However, I noticed that is not the case when using the export plugin. To clarify, if I have a controller with an action  as follows:

```
Class MyController {

  def exportMyContent {

      :
      :

    exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream,exportMaterial,fields, labels, [:], [:])
  }
}
```

Once the export is complete, the file is downloaded by the browser but the page does not change to export.gsp as it does in any other case.

Can someone explain why so?

Comment: You cannot send to the response both page and file at the same time.

Comment: Did you include 
render(view: "viewName")

Comment: No I did not. But I thought it is supposed to be convention over configuration, and that is how it is for other requests.